# How to check if class is Synchronized

Tags: java, class, synchronize

Should return true or false if class is synchronized.
I tried the class reflection and his function `isSynchronize` but it always returns false to me. I don't understand what this function checks? From what I know we can't write the the save word `synchronize` in the declaration of the class.

How do I check if the class I got from the user is synchronized?

Comment: Which "function" are you talking about? Classes aren't synchronized, methods are.

Comment: What `isSynchronized` are you referring to? The one in `java.lang.reflect.Modifier`?

Comment: Yes I reffer to the    java.lang.reflect.Modifier .  so What this function check?